# join two tables, error 1054 unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two tables by userid. I tried this:

```
select *
from crm_public.crm_user
join crm_sare.nl_user u on v.userid=u.userid
;
```

Unfortunately error occurs: *Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'v.userid' in 'on clause'*

What did I do wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try assing the alias and be sure of the correct column name

```
select *
from crm_public.crm_user as v
join crm_sare.nl_user as u on v.userid=u.userid
;
```