# MariaDB JOIN fails with 1054 Column not found, but FROM...WHERE from two tables works?

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

I am using PDO and ran into a strange issue with JOIN vs. the alternate syntax.

PHP version: PHP 7.1.7
The PDO module is for PHP7
MariaDB: 5.5.56-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1

When I run this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ShowsSetlists
JOIN Songs ON Songs.SongID = ShowsSetlists.SongID
WHERE ShowsSetlists.SongID = :id
```

With `array('id' => $songID);` as the parameter, where `$songID` is `int(28)` for example. But I get this error:

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ShowsSetlists.ShowID' in 'on clause'`

However, if I run the *same exact* query (case and all identical) on both HeidiSQL on Windows-side (the DB is in Vagrant ubuntu/trusty32) and within the MySQL console on the Vagrant box, the above query works just fine - no errors and the result is normal.

The same PDOException happens with an alias:

```
SELECT *
FROM ShowsSetlists
JOIN Songs AS s ON s.SongID = ShowsSetlists.SongID
WHERE ShowsSetlists.SongID = :id
```

Now, if I build the query with the alternate syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM ShowsSetlists sl, Songs s
WHERE 
    sl.SongID = s.SongID
    AND sl.ShowID = :id
```

Then it works and no PDOException is thrown.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't those two queries basically the same? Why the first one causes a PDOException?

I checked these questions, but they're not really related:
[Column not found: 1054 Unknown column using join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770088/column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-using-join)
[join two tables, error 1054 unknown column in 'on clause'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546880/join-two-tables-error-1054-unknown-column-in-on-clause)

The DB tables:

```
MariaDB [vortech]> DESCRIBE ShowsSetlists;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SetlistID    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ShowID       | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SongID       | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SetlistOrder | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [vortech]> DESCRIBE Songs;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SongID   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Title    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Duration | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [vortech]> DESCRIBE Shows;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ShowID      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ShowDate    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CountryCode | varchar(2)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Country     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| City        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Venue       | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you try by using aliases for both the tables, e.g.:

`SELECT * FROM ShowsSetlists ss JOIN Songs s ON s.SongID = ss.SongID
WHERE ss.SongID = :id`

Comment: Ùnfortunately ``SELECT * FROM ShowsSetlists ss JOIN Songs s ON s.SongID = ss.SongID WHERE ss.ShowID = :id`` gave the same: ``PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ss.SongID' in 'on clause'``

Comment: If the same query works fine from `HeidiSQL` then probably you are selecting different database while executing it from `php`? Maybe that database has different version of `ShowsSetlists` that does not have `SongID` column?

Comment: Sounds logical, but I verified that only one DB exists with the name in use, and no other instances forward ports to a different Vagrant DB for example. Only one DB server and only one DB exists with the name I use.

Comment: It actually gets more ridiculous. With ``SELECT sl.ShowID FROM ShowsSetlists sl, Songs s WHERE sl.SongID = s.SongID AND sl.ShowID = :id ORDER BY sl.ShowID ASC`` (I added ORDER BY) I get the same PDOException. But when I remove the ORDER BY, I get the sl.ShowID values just fine(!). This sounds more like an obscure bug in the specific setup.